# Python does not allow annotating the types of variables when unpacking

Tags: python, type-annotation

[PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations) says the following:

> Note that, although the syntax does allow tuple packing, it does not allow one to annotate the types of variables when tuple unpacking is used.

Why does python not support type annotations of variable while unpacking? 
PS. I am having to annotate the types first and then do the unpacking which is fine, except that annotating while unpacking would have been neater.

Comment: I mean, usually, whatever static-time type checker you are using can infer the correct types, if you've adequately typed the rest of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some information about this in the [Rejected/Postponed Proposals section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#rejected-postponed-proposals) of PEP 526:

> Allow type annotations for tuple unpacking: This causes ambiguity: it's not clear what this statement means:
>
> `x, y: T`
>
> Are x and y both of type T, or do we expect T to be a tuple type of two items that are distributed over x and y, or perhaps x has type Any and y has type T? (The latter is what this would mean if this occurred in a function signature.) Rather than leave the (human) reader guessing, we forbid this, at least for now.

The comment seems to suggest there may eventually be a proposal for a simpler syntax that isn't as prone to being misconstrued.  For now, we're left with having to annotate the tuple's types separately.